# How to match a word pattern n+ times

Tags: python, regex

Say, for instance, I have a word 'Anna' which I want to have appear twice or more in a string as the match condition. How do I represent this correctly in a regular expression (and not programmatically)?

Here's what I've tried:

---

**Test string**: `ANNA 3DDER murder ANNA`

With simple quantifier

```
"(ANNA){2,}"gm # No result
```

With positive lookahead

```
"(?=(ANNA){2,})"gm # No result
```

Catch-all

```
"(ANNA)"gm # Matches, but obviously not what we're looking for
```

Comment: Why not match 2 times ANNA like `^.*\bANNA\b.*\bANNA\b.*$`

Comment: You can also do: `s.count('ANNA')>=2`

Comment: `(?:.*?ANNA){2}` or `(?:.*?\bANNA\b){2}`. However, this is not Pythonic, and you'd better just use `len(re.findall(r'\bANNA\b', text)) == 2`

Comment: @Thefourthbird I just used `ANNA` as an example. Wanted a more general solution to cater for more complex expressions

Comment: @loaTzimas edited the post to clarify that I'm not looking for a programmatic solution